# angularjs: set selected item in dropdown from database

Tags: angularjs

I have few dropdowns with predefined field. Now i am making ajax call to database and fetch data.
Data is coming properly from the database and i can see the array in firebug(network tab).

I want to set this data as selected in dropdown. In textbox it is simple.
But i having hard time with dropdowns.

**Ajax code below**

```
formApp.controller('getprofile', function($scope,$http){
     $http({
                            url: 'get_profile.php',
                            method: "GET",
                            params: {uid: uid}
                         })
                    .success(function(data) {

                        if (data.success) {

                      $scope.formData.dob = data.dob;
                      $scope.married = data.married;
}
```

**Html code**

```
<input name="dob" id="dob" type="text" class="form-control textbox1" required="required" placeholder="Date of birth(dd-mm-yyyy) " ng-model="formData.dob">
<div class = "errorba" ng-show="dob">{{dob}}</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errormarried }">    
        <select id="married" name="married" class="selector form-control" ng-model="formData.married" required="required"> 

          <option value="0" selected="selected" >Maritial Status</option>
          <option value="1" >Single</option>
          <option value="2">Married</option>

        </select>
<span class="errorba" ng-show="errormarried">{{ errormarried }}</span>
</div>
```

Data from ajax - 1
1 means Single.

Please advise what am i doing wrong.

Comment: Share the response you get from the API call.

Comment: change `$scope.married = data.married;` to `$scope.formData.married = data.married;` in controller since your ng-model and $scope variable in your controller is different

Comment: @nivas it worked. Thank you. Please paste it in answer. So i can accept it.

Comment: okay, i have done it.

Comment: Better to use ng-options with ng-selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `$scope.married = data.married;` to `$scope.formData.married = data.married;` in controller since your `ng-model` and `$scope` variable in your controller is different.

In worst case you may get error `formData` as undefined in your controller. so define `$scope.formData = {};` before you use assign values to it.

```js
formApp.controller('getprofile', function($scope,$http){
     $http({
                            url: 'get_profile.php',
                            method: "GET",
                            params: {uid: uid}
                         })
                    .success(function(data) {

                        if (data.success) {
                      $scope.formData = {};
                      $scope.formData.dob = data.dob;
                      $scope.formData.married = data.married;
}
```